# Unable to define MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix as Const?

Tags: c#, constants, mathnet-numerics

Here is the C# code :

```
const MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<Complex32> ket_Zero =
   MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<Complex32>.Build.DenseOfRowMajor(2, 1,
       new MathNet.Numerics.Complex32[] {
           new MathNet.Numerics.Complex32(1,0),
           new MathNet.Numerics.Complex32(0,0)
       } );
```

It's ok if I don't put the const keyword.
But if I want to defined this as a constant, Microsoft Visual Studio rejects with

> Error Code CS0133 = The expression being assigned to 'Form1.ket_Zero' must be constant.

I also tried replacing `const` with `readonly` but won't work too.
How can I define matrices as constants?

Comment: Why exactly `readonly` doesn't work? What is the error?

Comment: If I use readonly, Visual Studio rejects with Error Code CS0191 = A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer)

Comment: Is `ket_Zero` a class field?

Comment: Yes. The definition is global within the System.Windows.Form class of Form1. I've just found out that readonly works and the error I got earlier is because after I defined it as readonly, another part of the program had tried to re-define it. Sorry. Just a second copy of the same lines within a method (causing the error) which I was using previously before attempting to put it in the global context. In summary, readonly works but const causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants#:%7E:text=Constants%20are%20immutable%20values%20which,may%20be%20declared%20as%20const%20.) on what can be defined as const. I will quote the required part.

> Only the C# built-in types (excluding System.Object) may be declared as const. User-defined types, including classes, structs, and arrays, cannot be const.

In your case, you are trying to define `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<Complex32>` as const but it is used declared type therefore can not be `const`

Comment: @Avon, I am glad to be of help